# Deploying a Play Framework 2.1 Application to Jelastic

Tags: playframework-2.0, jelastic

The resources I've found on this topic all seem to be related to Play 1.x. My application is built on Play 2.1 RC1. My application is built using sbt together with the sbt-Play plugin. I did not run the standard Play installer (meaning I do not have the "play" command.)

I've compiled and staged my application locally, which gives me a directory full of .jar files as well as a shell script called "start" which reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec java $@ -cp "`dirname $0`/staged/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`/..
```

I want to upload this directory to Jelastic and then tell it to run the script above. Unfortunately, all the documentation I've seen tells me to upload the .war file. How can I upload the directory to Jelastic, including the start script, and then tell Jelastic to run the start script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a solution: https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/ - it packages Play as a WAR.

I have succesfully built the WAR, currently trying to get the db setup working on Jelastic.